# The fastest way to check if the sub-list exists on the large list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have a list `list1` of about 1 000 000 sub-lists. Next, I would like to check if the given element `a`, which is a sub-list, exists in the list. Normally, it would be enough to check using `if a in list1`, but with a large list it works quite slowly. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you use tuples instead of lists?

Comment: I do not see any contraindications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state you can use tuples, I would recommend making each of your sub-lists into tuples and then making a `set` of these tuples. Then, searching the `set` will be an O(1) lookup. Initial construction of the set may be costly, though, but if you do many lookups it is worth it.

```
>>> set_of_sublists = {tuple(sublist) for sublist in orignal_list}
>>> tuple(sublist_to_check_for_membership) in set_of_sublists
```

---

I want to acknowledge that @BrettBeatty originally gave this answer as well but has deleted it subsequently.

Comment: I just noticed that he removed. although I do not know why, because the answer was actually good.